# COM in a Windows form EXE using Visual Basic/Visual Studio 12

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, com, automation, exe

I don't usually program in the .NET framework however I've needed to use it to create a simple exe application that logs data from some measurement equipment. I want this application to have an automation interface with a couple of methods. I've done this before using Delphi/Pascal and it was very straightforward, and I can create a Class Library in Visual Studio that registers itself and the methods and can easily be interfaced with but adding a ComClass to the windows form application doesn't work, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Why do you not want to use a class library?

Comment: I need the application to be running continuously, with user interaction through the GUI. Then I would like to be able invoke some methods and return values driven by another application.

Comment: I want to add a COM component as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd.aspx to a Windows Form Application to build an .exe,rather than a Class Library

Comment: It is just as easy to add a com class to an winform application as to a class library. You still have not explained your problem. What does not work? Inter-process communication is different from in-process communication, is that your issue? Also you should usually add any clarifications to the question, not the comments.

Comment: Apologies, When I add a comclass to a winform application the library does not seem to register when I build the application and I get an invalid program ID error when I try to access it from outside the application e.g WindowsApplication1.ComClass1. If I use the class Library, following the same steps, and try to interface.g ClassLibrary1.ComClass1 I can access the functions, methods, properties of the class without a problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This started as a comment but just kept growing, hopefully i am not off track ...

You can only register a dll. So the short answer would be to add a class library to your project and put the com class in there. This would allow you to share the functionality of the class, but *not the same instance of that class*.

I think your problem is that you are trying to establish [Interprocess Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). My immediate suggestion is not to do that, at least at first.

For a start you could have your com app interface with a .net class library which would log data. You could then have another project with a .net executable that displays the log, and updates periodically. Now you have .net code on both sides of the fence and can start investigating ways to get them to talk to each other.

The hard part is invoking methods and returning values. If you really need a responsive system you can investigate named pipes inter-process communication, or using a WCF service with callbacks between the two systems. The problem is that in either case you are hamstrung by the class library not being hosted by .net so you have limited functionality (no config file etc). If you can put up with a time lag I would suggest simply starting with writing messages to a local datastore and then polling from each client, every 30 seconds or so. For example the app would create a message saying "give me measurement A" and then start polling every second. The DLL would have a timer and within 30 seconds would read that message and write its own message with the measurement, which the EXE would read and then display. Once you get that system up and running you can decide whether you need to tackle inter-process communication, which is really just a different interface.